# How to use Django template filter in for loop?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

How can I filter specific field of a model in template while using for loop.

code:

```
    {% for news in news_list|position:3 %}

       <img class="d-block w-100 rounded slideimage" style="height:415px" src="{{news.image_link}}" alt="First slide">
                    <h1 class="mb-2">
                      {{news.title}}
                    </h1>
    {% endfor %}
```

there is a 'position' field in news model,I want to get all the news that position equal 3.I tried

```
 {% for news in news_list|position:3 %}
```

any friend can help?

Comment: please *don't* filter in the template. Filtering belongs to the *view*, since that is business logic, not rendering logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* filter in your template. Templates should only be concerned with making thinks look nice, not about the *content* of the things it is rendering. Filtering belongs in the *view*, since the view is concerned with *business logic*.

You thus filter with:

```
def myview(request):
    # …
    news_list = News.objects.filter(position=3)
    # …
    context = {
        'news_list' : news_list
    }
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but I have about 6 different positons,and I'm lazy,so I want to use the same simple view but different template filters,to do it.But I think there is no big differences of work whether I filter it in views or template,Thanks again!

Comment: @William: well it will not work. Django's template tags do not offer this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/ and Django's template language is *deliberately* restricted *not* to allow `.filter(position=3)`, etc. in the template, exactly to prevent people from doing that.

Comment: @William: if you need six different positions, you filter with `News.objects.filter(position__in=[1,3,6,10,15,17])` for example.